# Javascript Confirm with action?

Tags: javascript, html

wording this question was hard, but here i go. ok, i am using code from this site:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-getting-user-input-with-prompt-and-confirm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmInput()
{
  var ans = confirm("Install a virus and delete all your files?");

  alert(ans ? document.getElementById('level').value = "0"; 
              : "If no, do nothing");
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="confirmInput()" value="Show me the Question!" />
```

I have even tried to replace the Text for the answer with the actions, but i get nothing.

How do i add a action to the answer, so when it is yes, i do something, and when no i do not.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WTsMe/

Comment: sorry, i just updated it...i was in a hurry

Comment: Define "not work". You don't return the value from the confirm, if that's what you mean.

Comment: So, what's the issue?  `ans` will be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: like, if the answer is yes, the i want to do this....document.getElementById('level').value = "0";

Comment: Just use an [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.  `if(ans){document.getElementById('level').value = "0";}else{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function confirmInput()
{
    if(confirm("Install a virus and delete all your files?"))
        document.getElementById('level').value = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error in your code here:

```
alert(ans ? document.getElementById('level').value = "0"; // this semicolon is invalid
          : "If no, do nothing");
```

It executes till this semicolon and that terminates. Check your console, there should be an error message.

Another thing is that ?: operator can only return a value. It shouldn't contain operations, only values or function, which returns the value.